# After PHP upgrade from 5.3.1 to 5.3.2 session not working

Tags: php, linux, session

I upgraded the server and also php version from 5.3.1 to 5.3.2. The session stopped working dramatically. Login is working fine but it is not creating any session variables. When I try to check the session, it shows blank. After degrading PHP back to 5.3.1, the session works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: has the session path changed?

Comment: @marabutt No the session path is same as before.

Comment: your session path has "rw" access ?

Comment: May I ask why you are updating a 4 year old version of PHP to a 3,5 year old version of PHP ? That's completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the answer you expect, I guess, but you should just use the latest version from 5.3.x which as of now is 5.3.27. A lot of bug-fixes happened since 5.3.2 including some which are session-related

Comment: 5.3.2 was released on March 4, 2010. More than 3 years ago